# How to connect a UI Object to the Outlet of the cocoa class in Xcode 6 with swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, storyboard, xcode6

I have an application with 10 different View Controller Scenes in the Storyboard and 10 different Cocoa Touch classes. All of my Views are connected with segues. In every View  I have 2 `UITextField` Objects. When I started creating this application, by default there was  a View Controller Scene and a `ViewController.swift` class that I can connect the `UITextField` objects I put inside with the class Outlets using control+drag. This is something that I can't do to the rest of my View Controllers of the Storyboard with the rest of Cocoa Touch classes. I also tried any other way exist to make a referencing outlet from the object to the class.

How can I make this connection from the object to the class Outlet?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to assign the corresponding class file to the viewController in the identity inspector of InterfaceBuilder. After that, you can ctrl-drag from the control to that file to create the outlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the corresponding class name in properties :

[image]

Set the name of *.swift file to corresponding class, then after you can connect your control as `IBOutlet` in corresponding *.swift file.